# How do I redirect old ugly ulrs to nice urls

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to implement rewrite rules in my htaccess file but I am having difficulty implementing my specific requirements.  My mission is two-fold -

- re-**write** ugly urls to friendly urls.
- re-**direct** ugly urls to friendly urls.

To be specific - I would like Anyone visiting http://mywebsite.com/?section=abstract to be **redirected** to http://mywebsite.com/gallery/abstract

And then internally the url http://mywebsite.com/gallery/abstract is written back to http://mywebsite.com/?section=abstract  (but the user still sees the friendly url)

I have been able to get the latter bit working...

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)$ /?section=$1 [L]
```

But I don't know how to also redirect old/ugly urls to the nice ones.

Comment: If you don't intend to support the old URLs for the rest of time, you should probably be issuing "moved permanently" redirects.

Comment: Fixed - 'section' (old url)  'gallery' (new url)    Dynamic - 'abstract' (it is an example of the name of a photo gallery)

Comment: I am starting to think it will be easier to do this in my php code than trying to understand regex and rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to implement the redirect in PHP....

```
If(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"?section=")){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/gallery/$_GET[section]"); 

}
```