# How do I change ugly URLs to pretty URLs using .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I cannot for the life of me get this to work. I'm using this tutorial to make clean URLs: http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls.

So I have my domain, example.com, which is hosted using GoDaddy under the "Linux with cPanel control panel" plan. I uploaded a blank file called **index.php**. In the same folder, I uploaded **.htaccess** with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

When I type **example.com/index.php?page=blahblahblah**, the URL doesn't change to **example.com/blahblahblah** like it should. It doesn't change at all.

I've tried it on MAMP and it didn't work either. I tried changing the httpd.conf file for MAMP as well, but that didn't do anything.

I just need some pretty URLs, even if I have to manually say, "index.php?id=12344545 [goes to] example.com/mysubpage" for each individual page.

How can I achieve pretty URLs using .htaccess?

EDIT: I wasn't actually doing anything wrong with the .htaccess file, I just misunderstood a crucial concept pointed out my @Rasclatt:

"You have to change your links, not reformat what's in your address bar".

I just need to change my site's hyperlinks to the pretty URLs.

Comment: Have you tried the other way around? ie. type in `example.com/blahblahblah` and see if it resolves to `index.php?page=blahblahblah`? If it does, you just change all your links from a query link to a normal SEO link and it would resolve to the correct query.

Comment: mod_rewrite works on matching **incoming** URLs. It does not redirect by itself, or rewrite links in HTML templates. Secondary redirection RewriteRules are often used as *workaround*

Comment: Or [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772) and [How do I redirect old ugly ulrs to nice urls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16201609)

Comment: @Rasclatt yep, it does! Okay, I see. What do you mean, change all my links from a query link to a normal SEO link?

EDIT: You mean change all my site's hyperlinks to the pretty SEO-friendly links?

Comment: Yes, I was stuck on this concept for a very long time...until one day I just changed the link to see if it would work in reverse, and voila! You have to change your links, not reformat what's in your address bar

Comment: Thanks @Rasclatt! I finally get it. And thanks @mario for the references!